# Получение данных от сервера: исключение StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

```
private void gross_read (){
...
    System.out.println("Connect to ip:" +ip+" port:"+port);
    s = new Socket (ip, port);
    // читаем ответ
    buf = new byte[128*2048];
    r = s.getInputStream().read(buf);
    String data = new String(buf, 0, r); // в коде это строка 61
    System.out.println("Принято от сервера сообщение");
...
}

public void run(){
while (flag){
    try{
        gross_read();
        ...
    }catch(...){
        ...
    }
}
```

Сервер данные, не переставая, отсылает. Клиент получает, все красиво отображается. Но если прерывается поток, в котором прослушивается сокет, и вновь пытаюсь получать данные от сервера, всегда получаю что поток пуст. Выбрасывает эксепшон вот такой:

> `Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String
>  index out of range: -1
>         at java.lang.String.checkBounds(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
>         at vogon_ves.GrossVis.gross_read(GrossVis.java:61)
>         at vogon_ves.GrossVis.run(GrossVis.java:134)`

Что не так у меня?

---

Благодарю за ответы. но все же проблема для меня актуальна.
Суть в седеющем. Сервер - это устройство, весы. В документации к ним я нашел что они по указанному порту № хххх отсылают сообщение в с значением веса. При чем значение это мне надо получать постоянно, что было видно что динамику появления веса на платформе. Вот поэтому и пере создаю соединение к серверу.так как мне надо постоянно получать сообщения. И складывается такая ситуация, если не получаю сообщения в течения небольшого промежутка времени, минуты две, то всегда не могу прочитать поток. А если промежуток между получения сообщения секунд 20 то все порядке.  по поводу буфера, изначально мне смутила ошибка выхода за границы массива, вот я его сделал по больше. потом нашел туториал вычитал, что что за ексепшон выдает мне данный метон, и понял что дело не в размере буфера, а назад так и не уменьшил.

Comment: -1 в входящем потоке означает что закончилась передача данных. или вообще непередавались т.к. никто туда ничего и не записал.   

ваш код делает бесконечное количество соединений к серверу (возможно вы хотели сделать только одно?) и пытается считать ограниченное количество данных равных размеру буфера. обычно же считывание read делают в цыкле (пример с посимвольным считыванием):  

int a;
while ( -1 != ( ch = s.getInputStream().read() ) ) {...}


если все же это верная логика, 128*2048 byte это то количество данных которое вам надо, то возможно проблема с реализацией сервера

Comment: s.close();

Но это скорее всего не спасет. Мне кажется логика неверная.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что вы спрашиваете.

Вы имеете ввиду, почему вылазит исключение? Вот вы же сами сказали, что поток пуст. Следовательно `InputStream.read()` возвращает -1 - это невалидный индекс для индексирования массива. В JavaDoc к конструктору [String(byte[], int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) указано, что он выкидывает `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, если индексы неверны (точнее, `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, но это подкласс, так что технически верно).

Comment: так самое интересное, поток не может быть пустым, как как устройство всегда отсылает сообщения. А у клиента почему-то поток пуст?.. с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: С тем что устройство не посылает сообщения. Или вы не оттуда читаете.

Answer (score 1):

У вас всё не так. Буфер неоправданно велик, а результат чтения из сокета не проверяется. Нет также проверки на фрагментироване. Теоретически read может в любой момент сорваться с блокировки и вернуть вам 0. Но это не значит, что что-то было прочтено. А ваш код сработает так, будто чтение произошло. И да, индекс -1 получается потому, что r = -1 в случае, если соединение закрывается.

Comment: Доки для метода `InputStream.read()` (для версий, которые возвращают число прочитанных байт) утверждают, что 0 вернется, только если размер массива 0. При ошибке чтения (кроме конца потока) должно выкинутся исключение; при остальных случаях метод блокируется до того, как будет прчитан хоть один байт. У вас были другие ситуации?

Comment: Известно, что метод read в конечном итоге вызовет нативный метод read. А он, в свою очередь, может прочесть ноль байт в некоторых случаях, не являющихся ошибкой. Кроме того, нулевое чтение является частным случаем неполного чтения, которое точно возможно.